# loop through JSON file using ajax, PHP & Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

I'm creating a small game where users must register or login before playing. I have a separate json file that stores already registered users.

Once a user enters their username and password into a field I make an AJAX call to retrieve the data using PHP with the intent of checking whether their details are on file. Firstly I tried sending back a JSON encoded object to parse through in Javascript. This is the code I have so far:

JSON:

```
{"LogIns":[
   {
    "Username":"mikehene",
    "password":"123"
   },
   {
    "Username":"mike",
    "password":"123"
   }
]
}
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Please log in before playing</legend>
    <form>
        Username: <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Username" id="username1" name="username"><br>
        Password: <br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter a password" id="password" name="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return checkLogin();">
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];

$str = file_get_contents('logins.json'); // Save contents of file into a variable

$json = json_decode($str, true); // decode the data and set it to recieve data asynchronosly - store in $json

echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

Javascript & AJAX call:

```
var usernamePassed = '';

function checkLogin(){
    usernamePassed = document.getElementById("username1").value;
    callAJAX();
    return false;

}

function callAJAX(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            myFunction(xhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("POST", "LogInReg.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("username=" + usernamePassed);
}


function myFunction(response) {

    var arr = response;
    var objJSON = JSON.parse(arr);
    var len = objJSON.length;

    for(var key in objJSON){
        console.log(key);
    }
}
```

But it only prints out "LogIns". I also tried this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objJSON.length; ++i) {
                 if(objJSON[0].Username == usernamePassed){
                    console.log("found it");
                 }
                 else{
                    console.log("didn't find it!");
                 }
            }
```

Therefore I tried another approach (parse the data in the PHP file) like so:

```
foreach ($json['LogIns'][0] as $field => $value) {
        if($json['LogIns'][0]['Username'] == $username){
            echo "Logged In";
               break;
            }
            else{
                echo "No user found";
                break;
            }
        }
```

But when I enter "mike" as a user name it is echoing "No user found".  So I'm lost! I'm new to coding and trying to learn myself. I would love to learn how to do it both methods (i.e. PHP and Javascript).

Everything I've found online seems to push toward JQuery but I'm not quite comfortable/good enough at JQuery yet so would like to gradually work my way up to that.

I haven't even got to the register a user yet where I'm going to have to append another username and password on registration.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you print $json = json_decode($str, true); like echo '<pre>'; print_r($json);die; and paste output here.

Comment: Never send credentials or any useful data (not datum) to the client, as far as possible

Comment: Sachin Vairagi: Array
(
    [LogIns] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Username] => mikehene
                    [password] => 123
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Username] => mike
                    [password] => love
                )

        )

)

Comment: Salathiel: Don't worry I'm not planning on releasing this, it's purely for practice. But for future ref, do you mean not to send the data back to Javascript. Manipulate the data in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $json = json_decode($str, true);
 $password = $_POST['password'];

        foreach($json['LogIns'] as $res)
        {
            if($res['Username']==$username && $res['password']==$password)
            {
                echo json_encode($res['Username']);
               //echo 'user found'; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey Sachin, That prints both "user found" and "user not found" for an input of "mike"

Comment: Yes for the first entry 'mikehene' it is printing 'user not found' since you are submitting "mike" , for next entry when it founds "mike" , it is printing "user found", it is just an example (sample code) , please specify what you exactly want?

Comment: If it's found I need to pass the user onto the game page called "gamepage.html". Also I am creating a registration page to go along with this log in page that new users can register in.  How would I now append a new users username and password to LogIns in my json file?

Comment: Thanks Sachin! Much Appreciated!

Comment: YW! @MichaelHeneghan